# Which has a higher enol content between 4-Pyridone and Cyclohexa-2,5-dien-1-one?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, tautomer

[image: Enol content]

I am new to organic chemistry but here is what I feel. 4-Pyridone will have a lower enol content as in its keto form it has higher resonance stabilisation due to the involvement of lone pairs on nitrogen in conjugation while in the enol form the lone pair on nitrogen being in the molecular plane will not participate in resonance and thus will have an impact on resonance stabilisation. Thus the second compound(cyclohexadienone) will have higher enol content. Is my justification right?

Comment: __Hint:__ how much _relative_ stability does enol form provides in both the cases?

Comment: I think B>A is correct

Comment: What's more acidic? Ammonia or methane?